# Authenticate user from JUnit test case in case of Shiro FormAuthenticationFilter

Tags: spring, junit, shiro

I have a web application which uses shiro FormAuthenticationFilter to authenticate and authorize a user.
This is working very fine in the web application.

Now I have requirement to write test case which will call the resp API in the webapplication
and verify the integration test case(Rest layer(resource) -> Service layer -> Dao layer).

But to call the rest API I need to authenticate the user from junit and user principal 
should be available in the resoure layer.

I am using below line of code in rest layer to get logged in user and perform some task based on that.

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal().toString();
```

From the test cases I am not able to get the principle in rest layer.

My web application is running on Tomcat 7 server.

I can not mock the Subject in test cases because web application is running in Tomcat sever
and I am trying to access the rest from a jersey client.

**Is there any specific URL in shiro which I can call from any http client with user_name and password and it will 
authenticate the user and create session for him.**

How to achieve this, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#Allows all users with anypassword
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.AllowAllCredentialsMatcher
```

in the shiro.ini this will aloow any password that will work for testing purposes.

---

Also in case you waant a example 
Checkout this sample app. https://github.com/dominicfarr/skybird-shiro

It has three url paths configured in shiro.

web - uses form authentication.

api - uses basic authentication.

jersey - anonymous access.